# How to call .isNewUser() in authStateObserver in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Its not at all clear in the documentation how to check if a freshly logged in user has logged into my web app previously. There is an isNewUser() call referenced here:

[AdditionalUserInfo](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo)

What is not clear is how to get access to this call when using a firebase auth call and observer.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(authStateObserver);
```

The authStateObserver gets a user object after the person logs in using the provider specified. This user object cannot be used to call .isNewUser() so how does one get to the additionalUserInfo which has the call to .isNewUser() from inside this authStateObserver? This is in javascript in a web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` only triggers with the `FirebaseUser`. You can't get `additionalUserInfo` or any `credential` eg. OAuth tokens associated with the result from that observer. You have to get it from the `firebase.auth.UserCredential` after the sign-in promise resolves.

As these results are only available once on sign-in and Auth does not refresh OAuth credentials or actively update underlying OAuth profiles, Firebase Auth opted not to provide them in `onAuthStateChanged` listener as it could mislead developers to think that the listener can be used to listen/get new credentials or additional user data when in reality this information is only available once on sign-in.

The observer will only observe changed to the FirebaseUser, eg. sign-in or sign-out events.

Comment: I found that I can find isNewUser if I use the result of signInWithPopup(provider) which returns a credential. It does not work with signInWithRedirect(provider) because that returns a void. That would seem to be a problem if I want to make a progressive app which would require Redirect. So are you saying that whatever option I use I could get access to isNewUser also via auth after the sign process completes ... but not inside my onAuthStateChanged routine?

Comment: If you are using `signInWithRedirect`, you can get the result via `getRedirectResult` when the IdP redirects back and sign-in completes.

Answer (score 0):

For isNewUser(), go into the FirebaseUser class, click on the child class, it should take you to class zzn (for Android & as of now). Search for "isNewUser", you will find a field tagged with that string. It is zzj:

```
@Field(
        id = 10,
        getter = "isNewUser"
    )
    private boolean zzj;
```

Now search for the getter of that field, in my case it is:

```
public final boolean zzj() {
    return this.zzj;
}
```

So in your code base, this is the condition: `((zzn) firebaseUser).zzj()`

All you have to do is follow the Zzzzz letters. Smh (painful naming).